# Trying to comment a source file

Tags: bash, sed, match, quote

I am trying to comment lines of source so that something like
LANG                                  = 'ENG';
becomes
//         LANG                                  = 'ENG';

There are over a thousand lines in the source file and 'ENG' is not unique but the entire line IS.
I gave up on wild carding the spaces and just tried the entire extant line 'as-is' but no joy.
Something like (commented shell)--

`enter code here`

```
#!/bin/bash
#if [  -n "$5" ] ; then
#if [ "$5" == "ENG" ] ; then

sed -i "s/'         LANG                                   = '\''ENG'\''/\/\/'       LANG'                                  
=  '\''ENG'\''/" vc.pas > vc.out

#fi
#fi
```

So it reduces down to a single line. No joy whatever I try.
TIA !
Howie

Comment: Try `sed "s~.*LANG *= *'ENG';.*~//&~" vc.pas > vc.out`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, passing any whitespace through to the output:

```
$ echo "LANG='ENG';" | sed "s#^\(\s*LANG\s*=\s*'ENG'\s*;\)#// \1#"
// LANG='ENG';
$ echo "   LANG  = 'ENG'  ;   " | sed "s#^\(\s*LANG\s*=\s*'ENG'\s*;\)#// \1#"
//    LANG  = 'ENG'  ;
```

Technically it needs double backslashes inside the double-quoted string, but because none of the sequences form a valid escape sequence, bash doesn't mind.

Comment: My sed doesn't understand `\s` or `\S`, can you include a portable solution please?

Comment: Sorry about that. Replace `\s` by `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: THANK YOU Thomas ! Could you clarify what the # does in the SED statement ??

Comment: Ok, I think the # is just a place holder in lieu of '/' like , say,  ':' (colon)

Comment: `s/foo/bar/` can be written `s#foo#bar#`. Any character after the `s` becomes the pattern delimiter.

Comment: @ryszard  alas, real world many lines - most beginning with comment '//' when i run the above solutions. the line without '//' becomes '////////////' followed by expect LANG = 'ENG';

Comment: depending on which language being compiled i would like to comment or uncomment the source. REF: https://github.com/n4af/TR4W/blob/master/tr4w/src/VC.pas  lines 149 thru 157. using solutions to comment '//' the first line 'ENG', I get twelve slashes- I really would like only two slashes ?

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed, use

```
sed -i "s,.*LANG *= *'ENG';.*,//&," vc.pas
```

where

- `-i` - enables inline file modification
- `s` - substitution command
- `,` - delimiter
- `.*LANG *= *'ENG';.*` - text containing `LANG = 'ENG';` with any amount of spaces around `=`
- `//&` - replaces the matched line with `//` and the line itself

Comment: The above produces: ////////          LANG                                  = 'ENG';

Comment: @HowieHoyt No, it [works as expected](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9hWScHH0c9dwVZB3dXPXd1aias4NUVBqVhHTwssrmWroAWR0dPS0ddX01FSsLGxUVBSKVb6/x8A).

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression for the line selection, followed by a substitution.  Put the replacement commands in a file:

```
$ cat dt.sed                                                                                                      
/^LANG[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*'[^']*'/s;^;// ;
$
```

Then run sed(1) with that script:

```
$ echo "LANG='FOO'" | sed -f dt.sed
// LANG='FOO'
```

This works on a Fedora 34 system, but should work on any Linux.